# How to simulate the tag touch from other application

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, intentfilter, ndef

I want to simulate the touch event for my application. My manifest is like

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.TagActivity_"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.NFC"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
            android:host="ext"
            android:pathPrefix="/abc:d"
            android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Question (1): I want to invoke my application from other application. How do I do that? My current code is like:

```
try {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    NdefMessage ndefMessage = buildNdefMessage(getTagData());
    intent.putExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES, new NdefMessage[] {ndefMessage});
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But this is not invoking my application. probably because the data type and path prefix do not match. How do I pass this while starting the activity?

Question (2): For temp purpose I have added

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

to make it work, and my application is invoked. But while reading the tag I check the tag type, and since I am not passing any tag type, my app crashes. So how do I create a tag instance? There is no constructor for this. I mean I can't do `Ndef ndef = new Ndef();`. And I don't basically have a tag so I can't event do `Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);`.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding question (1): How to invoke `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter**

Your activity ".activity.TagActivity_" filters has two different `NDEF_DISCOVERED`. The first one matches if the intent contains a URI of the form "vnd.android.nfc://ext/abc:d". The second one matches if the intent contains a data type of "text/plain".

Consequently, you need to either add a matching URI or a matching MIME type to the intent that you use to start that activity.

1. MIME type "text/plain":

   ```
   final Intent intent = new Intent(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
   intent.setType("text/plain");
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. URI "vnd.android.nfc://ext/abc:d":

   ```
   final Intent intent = new Intent(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("vnd.android.nfc://ext/abc:d"));
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

Any of the two will start your activity.

**NOTE** that you specified `android:permission="android.permission.NFC"` for your receiving activity. You normally would not do that. Specifying this permission means that your sending application needs to have that permission.

**Regarding question (2): How to pass a mock tag object?**

It's possible to create a mock tag object instance using reflection (note that this is not part of the public Android SDK, so it might fail for future Android versions).

1. Get the `createMockTag()` method though reflection:

   ```
   Class tagClass = Tag.class;
   Method createMockTagMethod = tagClass.getMethod("createMockTag", byte[].class, int[].class, Bundle[].class);
   ```
2. Define some constants for preparing a valid mock NDEF tag instance:

   ```
   final int TECH_NFC_A = 1;
   final String EXTRA_NFC_A_SAK = "sak";    // short (SAK byte value)
   final String EXTRA_NFC_A_ATQA = "atqa";  // byte[2] (ATQA value)

   final int TECH_NDEF = 6;
   final String EXTRA_NDEF_MSG = "ndefmsg";              // NdefMessage (Parcelable)
   final String EXTRA_NDEF_MAXLENGTH = "ndefmaxlength";  // int (result for getMaxSize())
   final String EXTRA_NDEF_CARDSTATE = "ndefcardstate";  // int (1: read-only, 2: read/write, 3: unknown)
   final String EXTRA_NDEF_TYPE = "ndeftype";            // int (1: T1T, 2: T2T, 3: T3T, 4: T4T, 101: MF Classic, 102: ICODE)
   ```
3. Create an NDEF message:

   ```
   NdefMessage ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain"), "Text".getBytes("US-ASCII"));
   ```
4. Create the tech-extras bundle for a Type 2 tag with that NDEF message:

   ```
   Bundle nfcaBundle = new Bundle();
   nfcaBundle.putByteArray(EXTRA_NFC_A_ATQA, new byte[]{ (byte)0x44, (byte)0x00 }); //ATQA for Type 2 tag
   nfcaBundle.putShort(EXTRA_NFC_A_SAK , (short)0x00); //SAK for Type 2 tag

   Bundle ndefBundle = new Bundle();
   ndefBundle.putInt(EXTRA_NDEF_MAXLENGTH, 48); // maximum message length: 48 bytes
   ndefBundle.putInt(EXTRA_NDEF_CARDSTATE, 1); // read-only
   ndefBundle.putInt(EXTRA_NDEF_TYPE, 2); // Type 2 tag
   ndefBundle.putParcelable(EXTRA_NDEF_MSG, ndefMessage);  // add an NDEF message
   ```
5. Prepare an anti-collision identifier/UID for your tag (see `Tag.getId()` method). E.g. a 7-byte-UID for a Type 2 tag:

   ```
   byte[] tagId = new byte[] { (byte)0x3F, (byte)0x12, (byte)0x34, (byte)0x56, (byte)0x78, (byte)0x90, (byte)0xAB };
   ```
6. Then you can create a mock tag instance by invoking the `createMockTag()` method

   ```
   Tag mockTag = (Tag)createMockTagMethod.invoke(null,
           tagId,                                     // tag UID/anti-collision identifier (see Tag.getId() method)
           new int[] { TECH_NFC_A, TECH_NDEF },       // tech-list
           new Bundle[] { nfcaBundle, ndefBundle });  // array of tech-extra bundles, each entry maps to an entry in the tech-list
   ```

Once you created that mock tag object, you can send it as part of the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent:

```
Intent ndefIntent = new Intent(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
ndefIntent.setType("text/plain");
ndefIntent.putExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID, tagId);
ndefIntent.putExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG, mockTag);
ndefIntent.putExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES, new NdefMessage[]{ ndefMessage });
```

Optionally, you can explicitly define your target activity as the receiving component:

```
ndefIntent.setComponent(...); // or equivalent
```

You can then send this intent to your activity:

```
startActivity(ndefIntent);
```

The receiver can then use the moch tag object to retrieve instances of the technology classes (e.g. `Ndef.get(tag)`) but any method that requires IO operations will **fail**.